# Password safety

Tags: security, passwords

[image]
Many of you probably know this image. Some would argue that it's very vulnerable to dictionary attacks, so I wrote my own password generator. I'm using the default 2048 word list of the [bitcoin passphrase](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt), additionally adding a single number, symbol and uppercase letter.

If using a password manager (e.g. Lastpass), I can easily create something like this:

```
#guwV&zMot#v2YJE0^!x5vCnd1M$r&MNCvJgP*j7k3v6F5nM#hf1jUITOl^HP&D9
```

But entering this string on your smartphone isn't fun at all. Here some examples how my generated passwords look like ([source code](http://pastebin.com/HsUK7nAi)):

```
pull 2 mule slot F milk lecture treat crew _ dry amateur pyramid
hole # agree domain 9 execute exist loud column bounce G another
pledge 4 moral rely slow _ fork M tired fame razor cradle derive
report ! crop addict choice fiction fashion 9 mail W sun weather
```

My thought is this:
The attacker tries a dictionary attack - without success because of the extra characters. So next try would be bruteforce (lowercase letters). After that he need to try uppercase letters, numbers and symbols too. Because he doesn't know the length of my password and the quantity of numbers/symbols/uppercase letters, he has to try all possible combinations.

So not knowing the pattern and length of the password and the easy interchangeability/modification of the dictionary, chars, numbers and symbols, it should be as strong as the one Lastpass generated. Is my idea correct or am I missing something and this passwords aren't that much safer either?

(Edit) Updated the source code: replaced $RANDOM with a function which generates a random number from /dev/random, added some comments and variable names are clearer now.

Comment: Smart attackers aren't restricted to plain dictionary attacks. Their password cracker can try variations of dictionary words, concatenation of several words, etc. When you write a password generator, you should assume that the attacker knows the algorithm used to generate the password but not the seed of the CSPRNG.

Comment: The link to your paste doesn't work. Says that it's a private paste.

Comment: Ten words picked from a list of 2048 words results in a 110 bit password, which is very strong. (assuming your implementation doesn't suck).

Comment: Paste should work now. Implementation isn't really outstanding... just hacked together few lines of code to get something working.

Comment: I doubt the bash rng is secure. I wouldn't be surprised if it used a 32 bit seed (typical for non crypto PRNGs), which would limit the security to 32 bits.

Comment: I always wondered why using $RANDOM should be insecure. How could someone hacking a MySQL database know which random numbers and especially which algorithm I used to generate the password? But whatever... would be `rand=$(($(grep -m1 -ao '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' /dev/random)%10))` or `rand=$(($(echo $(od -An -N2 -i /dev/random))%10))` random enough?